# Passing data to and fro during run time between C# Winform and Python Script, using Ironpython

Tags: winforms, ironpython, named-pipes, simulator, dynamic-language-runtime

When I click the button On winform, this get executed:

```
using (var outStream = new ScriptOutputStream(win.txtOutput))
{
    ExecuteScript(outStream);
}
```

This is the function to run the script.

```
private void ExecuteScript(Stream outputStream)
{
    var ipy = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntime(); 
    engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.GetEngine(ipy);
    engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(outputStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
    scope = engine.CreateScope();
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"trial.py", scope);       
}
```

`ScriptOutputStream()` is my function that will create an object of the textbox and just write from the buffer into it. No problem there.
This outputs the Python Console into the text box.

How do I pass data from another button click, to `trial.py`, and once `trial.py` runs, read input back from it. 
The python thread must also be running on it's own thread simultaneously, and be listening for inputs.

Comment: Show us what you already tried, and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I rewrote it. All this is working well. How would you suggest I progress from here?